# How to change letter SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-masking

I change word letters (5 AND 6 letter changing) and some letter masking. But I take error change letter and I don't do masking.

My query:

```
SELECT
    NAME,
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(NAME, 1, 4),
           SUBSTRING (NAME, 6, 1),
           SUBSTRING(NAME, 5, 1),
           SUBSTRING(NAME, 7, LEN(NAME) -5))
FROM
    INFORMATION
```

This error is

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

How can I do? (SQL Server 2014.)

Comment: share your sample data and output

Comment: This data is  ID and Name.ID:1 and Name:Weather

Comment: @user10181472 if you really wants help from others then your question should be clear and proper informative , so if just put your table name with column value in your question then it is helpful for others to get your problem hope you got my point

Comment: ID Name Status
1 Weather Good
2 Days DaysNumber     I keep days information and days weather.I try easy sample database and I want to try how I can do?

Comment: You've asked the exact same question twice, except that 3&4 are replaced with 5&6.  Please see my answer to the other question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51695230/how-to-masking-format-some-letter-in-sql-server-2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you're passing -5 to length of the column "NAME" which is less than 5 and the function `SUBSTRING` can't accept negative values. If you want to avoid that you can always add `ABS` to you expression, however, you need to verify that it is returning what you are expecting:

```
SELECT
    NAME,
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(NAME, 1, 4),
           SUBSTRING(NAME, 6, 1),
           SUBSTRING(NAME, 5, 1),
           SUBSTRING(NAME, 7, ABS(LEN(NAME) -5)))
FROM
    INFORMATION
```